# Track error on file permission?

Tags: files

I get this error when running Status Report:

> CTools CSS Cache  Unable to create
>
> The CTools CSS cache directory, ctools/css could not be created due to a misconfigured files directory. Please ensure that the files directory is correctly configured and that the webserver has permission to create directories.

Where should I look for this folder?

Answer (score 1):

That should be in the base of your site's file directory. Navigate to **/admin/config/media/file-system** to see where it is configured.